# Is there a fully customizable UIPickerView-like open source component for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipickerview

I need to customize the appearance of a UIPickerView but as far as I know it is not possible. Before re-inventing the wheel... is there a open source reproduction of UIPickerView which allows for using custom UI images for the picker itself?

Comment: You mean images to be selected? That is already possible with the standard API.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's pretty easy to customize the appearance of a UIPickerView. All you need to do is to layout the gfx over the picker so your gfx will cover the original gfx.